# How to index outliers?

Tags: r, dataframe, outliers

I have the data below. How can I determine which author has the highest number of publications?

I try this

```
   (which(status$researchers==max(status$publications))
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#PUBLICATIONS

researchers = c("Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Brown", "Jones", "Miller", "Davis", "García", "Rodriguez", "Wilson", "Martinez", "Anderson", "Taylor", "Thomas", "Hernandez", "Moore", "Martin", "Jackson", "Thompson", "White", "Lopez", "Lee", "Gonzalez", "Harris", "Clark", "Lewis", "Robinson", "Walker", "Perez", "Hall", "Young", "Allen", "Sanchez", "Wright", "King", "Scott", "Green", "Baker", "Adams", "Nelson", "Hill", "Ramirez", "Campbell", "Mitchell", "Roberts", "Carter", "Phillips", "Evans", "Turner", "Stapel", "Torres", "Parker", "Collins", "Edwards", "Stewart", "Flores", "Morris", "Nguyen", "Murphy", "Rivera", "Cook", "Rogers", "Morgan", "Peterson", "Cooper", "Reed", "Bailey", "Bell", "Gomez", "Kelly", "Howard", "Ward", "Cox", "Diaz", "Richardson", "Wood", "Watson", "Brooks", "Bennett", "Gray", "James", "Reyes", "Cruz", "Hughes", "Price", "Myers", "Long", "Foster ", "Sanders", "Ross", "Morales", "Powell", "Sullivan", "Russell", "Ortiz", "Jenkins", "Gutierrez", "Perry", "Butler", "Barnes", "Fisher", "De Jong", "Jansen", "De Vries", "vd Berg", "Van Dijk", "Bakker", "Janssen", "Visser", "Smit", "Meijer", "De Boer", "Mulder", "De Groot", "Bos", "Smeesters", "Vos", "Peters", "Hendriks", "Van Leeuwen", "Dekker", "Brouwer", "De Wit", "Dijkstra", "Smits", "De Graaf", "Van der Meer", "Muller", "Schmidt", "Schneider", "Fischer", "Meyer", "Weber", "Schulz", "Wagner", "Becker", "Hoffmann", "Wagemakers",  "Molenaar", "Jansen", "White", "Bargh", "Dijksterhuis", "Poldermans", "Kanazawa", "Lynne", "Ling", "Vorst", "Borsboom", "Wicherts")

articles = data.frame(cbind(researchers, publications))
write.table(articles, file = "scientific status.txt", sep = " ")

status = read.table("scientific status.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "", quote = "\"'")
```

Comment: I don't think how you create the data, even less the `{write,read}.table` steps are relevant here. It would be a lot more useful if you gave a sample of your data, please refer to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Well, I thought it would be useful to create be able to create the data.

Comment: But what are the contents of `status` ?  Unless they are integers, you're unlikely to get any matches.  Your `researchers` vector has no numbers so `max` is going to do interesting things with those character strings.

Comment: How are you defining "outlier"?

Answer (score 2):

It is not a general response but here you need just to extract duplicated.

```
researchers[duplicated(researchers)]
[1] "Jansen" "White"  ## this 2 authors have 1 publications more than others!
```

To see the ouliers you can do this for example :

```
plot(table(researchers))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what your data represents. If it is already aggregated per author, i.e., there is one row per author and the `publications` column contains the number of publications, do:

```
status$researchers[which.max(status$publications)]
```

If instead, your data is not aggregated, i.e., there is one per article, you can do:

```
tail(sort(table(status$researchers)), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps. And what about the situation where I want to know the name of the researcher who published, say, 30, articles?

Comment: If your data is already aggregated, `subset(status, publications >= 30)`. If it is not aggregated, `which(table(researchers) >= 30`.